# ob_start file_put_contents timeout when more than one record is requested from mysql

Tags: php, ob-start, file-put-contents

Here is my code

```
<?php
ini_set("default_socket_timeout", 60);
include("include/dbcommon.php");
ob_start();
include("inspections_print.php");
$page_content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
file_put_contents('files/bobby3.html',$page_content);

?>
```

The inspections_print.php request records from a mysql database and builds a report.   It works and creates the bobby3.html file if it only request 1 record, if I request 10 records it creates an empty bobby3.html file.  This on a Linode server that I have complete control over.  It is set to use `1024M` of memory `max_execution_time` = 300 and `default_socket_timeout` = 300

Comment: you should extend the timeout or remove the line ini_set("default_socket_timeout", 60) on your php file since the configuration is set already to 300 seconds as mentioned above.

Comment: @Shudmeyer Why would the timeout matter? If the script is stopping because of a timeout it won't create `bobby3.html` at all, not create an empty file.

Comment: @Barmar, yup it will create an empty file not the contents. we don't exactly what is the query involved on the inspections_print.php (10 records) which make take too long to execute, when it does the contents of bobby3.html will result to empty since timeout is set to 60 seconds

Comment: I have found out that the issue is a javascript generated page break that the inspections_print.php is including from another file as it breaks on 2 records and with only 2 records does place some of the js file calls in the bobby3.html.